# protobuf in the android grpc sample app generating extra package heirarchy called "nano"

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to build a sample android app for grpc.

**The hello_world.proto file is as follows:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.github.caio.grpc";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
  rpc GetData (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

The **gradle** files are as follows.

**App level gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.grpctest.grpcandroidapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.12.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                javanano {
                    // Options added to --javanano_out
                    option 'ignore_services=true'
                }
            }

            task.plugins {
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'nano'
                }
            }

            task.plugins {
                grpc {
                    // Write the generated files under
                    // "$generatedFilesBaseDir/$sourceSet/grpcjava"
                    outputSubDir = ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:0.12.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:0.12.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:0.12.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}
```

**Project level gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

With this .proto file, we should have got a package structure for the generated Java files as follows:

io->grpc->examples->helloworld

But the HelloRequest and the HelloResponse files generated are in the following package structure:

io->grpc->examples->helloworld->nano

The GreeterGrpc.java file however is generated in the right package structure.

The "HelloRequest" and the "HelloResposne" imports in the GreeterGrpc refer to the io.grpc.examples.helloworld package and hence compilation is failing.

Please let me know a solution to this problem.

Comment: FYI the current code generator is version 13, not 12 in your grade file:

artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.12.0'

Comment: @Carl : Thanks for the response. I did change the versions to 13 in the gradle. It did not help though. The same problem persists.        
dependencies {compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:0.13.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:0.13.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:0.13.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grpc-java 0.13 and earlier requires using `option 'nano=true'`. grpc-java 0.14 will support `option 'nano'` in addition.

Comment: I changed **option 'nano'** to **option 'nano=true'**. Problem is solved. Generated files are having nano in their import statements. Thank you so much.. :)...yayy... :D